# Maven archetype properties with default value artifactID

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I want to make an archetype that use a parameter to be created...nut I don't know if is right a parameter made in this way:

```xml
<requiredProperties>
    <requiredProperty key="appName">
        <defaultValue>${artifactId}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

It's not working for me...i've a failure on the integration-test

```
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:integration-test (default-integration-test) @webapp-archetype ---
[ERROR] Archetype test.archetype:webapp-archetype:1.0-SNAPSHOT is not configured
    Property appName is missing.
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeNotConfigured: Archetype test.archetype:webapp-archetype:1.0-SNAPSHOT is not configured
    Property appName is missing.
```

Answer (score 23):

Edit `test/resources/projects/basic/archetype.properties` and add `appName=artifactID` there.