# Maven create archetype: Is there a way to declare properties (defaulted to a value) so as not to have them prompted?

Tags: maven, properties, prompt, required, archetypes

I am working on creating a maven archetype. It is working fine. I have one more enhancement to do which is explained below

In the `archetype-metadata.xml`, I declared the following properties.

```
<requiredProperties>
        <requiredProperty key="item1">
            <defaultValue>${artifactId}_1</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
        <requiredProperty key="item2">
            <defaultValue>${artifactId}_2</defaultValue>
        </requiredProperty>
</requiredProperties>
```

When I create the project, it is prompting for the required properties as it should.

All I need is NOT to prompt for these values (which would force to accept the default values) while creating the project?

So, my question: is there a way to declare properties (defaulted to a value) so as not to have them prompted?

Comment: did you try without using variable in the defaultValue ? 
<defaultValue>some_example_1</defaultValue> instead of <defaultValue>${artifactId}_1</defaultValue>

Comment: I tried that, but it prompts. <defaultValue> will be considered if the user does not enter anything when prompted. However, in my example above I would need the ${artifactId} anyways.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583786/maven-archetype-properties-with-default-value-artifactid