# Maven custom archetype: Is there a way to have properties not prompted to the user?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

So I am doing an archetype and I want to use some properties but don´t want them to be prompted to the user.

So for example, I have this code:

```
    <requiredProperty key="grupo">
        <defaultValue>${artifactId.substring(0,8).toLowerCase()}</defaultValue>
    </requiredProperty>
```

And I want to use the defaultValue for the parameter grupo WITHOUT asking the user to accept it as the default value.

This question was already asked: [Maven create archetype: Is there a way to declare properties (defaulted to a value) so as not to have them prompted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34021316/maven-create-archetype-is-there-a-way-to-declare-properties-defaulted-to-a-val) But it was not answered.

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem you can actually do that: https://maven.apache.org/archetype/archetype-models/archetype-descriptor/archetype-descriptor.html#class_requiredProperty

According the documentation you can specify a default or a validation regex. If they are declared you will be prompted with de default value.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this functionality is now supported.

If you specify a default value, it will not be prompted for unless you specify

`-DaskForDefaultPropertyValues`

Found a reference to it in the source code:

https://github.com/apache/maven-archetype/blob/master/maven-archetype-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/archetype/mojos/CreateProjectFromArchetypeMojo.java

Also in the documentation :

https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/generate-mojo.html